# Is there a practical way to broadcast and receive ascii payloads over ethernet or wifi?

Tags: serial, wifi, ethernet, networking

How best might arduino nodes pass incoming serial ascii messages out as ascii network broadcasts for all others to receive and pass out through their serial ports?

ie: typing a msg from the IDE serial monitor of any ethernet node should cause that msg to be output to the serial monitors of all other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The magical trick you are looking for is Ethernet UDP Broadcast. By chance there is an example sketch in the [Arduino Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString). I cannot say if it is up to date but this will help you get started.

Cheers!

Comment: That looks to be an excellent starting point for what I'm trying to do, thank you very much indeed Mikael.

Comment: Something crucial in the example is puzzling me...
The arduino is a listening UDP client which returns an acknowledgement to any sender(s). But the processing sketch which should be broadcasting a message seems to only be sending it to the specified client, rather than globally to all listening clients...
void keyPressed() {
 String ip       = "192.168.1.177"; // remote IP address
 int port        = 8888;        // destination port
 udp.send("Hello World", ip, port );   // message to send
 }
Is it possible to broadcast to all of the subnet by using something like 0 as the address byte?

Comment: More reading https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_UDP_multicast.